# Flask in production mode ignores @app.errorhandler

Tags: flask

In debug mode, @app.errorhandler works, but in production, I have to set PROPOGATE_EXCEPTIONS=1 to get the behavior. I am wondering why (security reason?). Secondly, with PROPOGATE_EXCEPTIONS set, do I still get error logging (when there is no flask errorhandler for a given Exception)? By the look of the Flask source code, it does not, and am wondering how I can get logging in this case. My initial thought is to set a flask error handler for Exception, which is more general and ought to be hit last, in which I log and return 500. Is this the right pattern?

I am using Flask 1.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit was flask_restful overriding flask's error handling behavior. The workaround found at https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/issues/280#issuecomment-280648790 restores flask's error handling.

```
handle_exceptions = app.handle_exception
handle_user_exception = app.handle_user_exception
api = Api(app)
app.handle_user_exception = handle_exceptions
app.handle_user_exception = handle_user_exception
```